R crashes when I import raster layers (ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61)
I am working with R (4.4.0) in RStudio (2024.4.1.748) in Ubuntu 22.04.
When I try to import a raster with the terra package (but also with raster package) I got this error and R crashes:
r <- rast("file.tif")

[24697:24697:20240606,175745.757656:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[24697:24697:20240606,175745.757843:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[24697:24698:20240606,175745.781125:ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir: No such file or directory (2)

This is the first time I see this error, but I think it is related to GDAL on my laptop. However I already removed and re-installed GDAL following this but nothing changed. I also re-installed R, RStudio, terra and raster but again nothing.
I am running out of options here so many thanks to any kind of help!

try this one, does this work: pathraster <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra");r <- rast(pathraster) ?

Hi, no it did not work. I got the same error

OK, I would check previous versions of R and terra, also check on other machines with different OS. Basically process of elimination to figure out what is causing the error.
